# Row with 5 columns

Tags: bootstrap-5

I am building an e-commerce website on bootstrap, but I am quite new to this world of web design (quite new on programing tbh), and I am trying to build a row with 5 colluns to display some products, but I tried a lot of things and I can't make the row with 5 cols without compromising the website responsiveness, any help?

```html
  <div class="container-fluid  py-5 m-0">
        <div class="container-fluid m-0">
            <div class="row g-0 gx-5 align-items-end">
                <div class="col-lg-6">
                    <div class="section-header text-start mb-5">
                        <span class="display-5 mb-3 fw-bolder">Os Nossos produtos</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-6 text-lg-end position-relative" style="bottom: 50px;">
                    <h5><a href="" class="mb-3" style="text-decoration: none;">View All <i
                                class="fa-solid fa-arrow-right"></i></a></h5>

                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="tab-content">
                <div id="tab-1" class="tab-pane p-0 active">
                    <div class="row g-0">
                        <div class="col-xl-2 col-lg-2.4 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-6">
                            <div class="product-item">
                                <div class="position-relative bg-light overflow-hidden">
                                    <img class="img-fluid w-100" src="img/imagensMiguel/produto_1.jpeg" alt="">

                                </div>
                                <div class="p-4">
                                    <a class="d-block h5 mb-2" href="">Fresh Tomato</a>
                                    <span class="text-primary me-1">$19.00</span>
                                    <span class="text-body text-decoration-line-through">$29.00</span>
                                </div>
                                <div class="d-flex ">
                                    <small class="w-50 text-center py-2">
                                        <a class="text-body" href=""><i
                                                class="fa fa-shopping-bag text-primary me-2"></i>Add to cart</a>
                                    </small>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xl-2 col-lg-2.4 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-6">
                            <div class="product-item">
                                <div class="position-relative bg-light overflow-hidden">
                                    <img class="img-fluid w-100" src="img/imagensMiguel/produto_2.jpeg" alt="">

                                </div>
                                <div class="p-4">
                                    <a class="d-block h5 mb-2" href="">Fresh Tomato</a>
                                    <span class="text-primary me-1">$19.00</span>
                                    <span class="text-body text-decoration-line-through">$29.00</span>
                                </div>
                                <div class="d-flex ">

                                    <small class="w-50 text-center py-2">
                                        <a class="text-body" href=""><i
                                                class="fa fa-shopping-bag text-primary me-2"></i>Add to cart</a>
                                    </small>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xl-2 col-lg-2.4 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-6">
                            <div class="product-item">
                                <div class="position-relative bg-light overflow-hidden">
                                    <img class="img-fluid w-100" src="img/imagensMiguel/produto_3.png" alt="">

                                </div>
                                <div class=" p-4">
                                    <a class="d-block h5 mb-2" href="">Fresh Tomato</a>
                                    <span class="text-primary me-1">$19.00</span>
                                    <span class="text-body text-decoration-line-through">$29.00</span>
                                </div>
                                <div class="d-flex ">

                                    <small class="w-50 text-center py-2">
                                        <a class="text-body" href=""><i
                                                class="fa fa-shopping-bag text-primary me-2"></i>Add to cart</a>
                                    </small>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xl-2 col-lg-2.4 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-6">
                            <div class="product-item">
                                <div class="position-relative bg-light overflow-hidden">
                                    <img class="img-fluid w-100" src="img/imagensMiguel/produto_1.jpeg" alt="">

                                </div>
                                <div class=" p-4">
                                    <a class="d-block h5 mb-2" href="">Fresh Tomato</a>
                                    <span class="text-primary me-1">$19.00</span>
                                    <span class="text-body text-decoration-line-through">$29.00</span>
                                </div>
                                <div class="d-flex ">

                                    <small class="w-50 text-center py-2">
                                        <a class="text-body" href=""><i
                                                class="fa fa-shopping-bag text-primary me-2"></i>Add to cart</a>
                                    </small>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xl-2 col-lg-2.4 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-6">
                            <div class="product-item">
                                <div class="position-relative bg-light overflow-hidden">
                                    <img class="img-fluid w-100" src="img/imagensMiguel/produto_2.jpeg" alt="">

                                </div>
                                <div class=" p-4">
                                    <a class="d-block h5 mb-2" href="">Fresh Tomato</a>
                                    <span class="text-primary me-1">$19.00</span>
                                    <span class="text-body text-decoration-line-through">$29.00</span>
                                </div>
                                <div class="d-flex ">

                                    <small class="w-50 text-center py-2">
                                        <a class="text-body" href=""><i
                                                class="fa fa-shopping-bag text-primary me-2"></i>Add to cart</a>
                                    </small>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xl-2 col-lg-2.4 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-6">
                            <div class="product-item">
                                <div class="position-relative bg-light overflow-hidden">
                                    <img class="img-fluid w-100" src="img/imagensMiguel/produto_3.png" alt="">

                                </div>
                                <div class=" p-4">
                                    <a class="d-block h5 mb-2" href="">Fresh Tomato</a>
                                    <span class="text-primary me-1">$19.00</span>
                                    <span class="text-body text-decoration-line-through">$29.00</span>
                                </div>
                                <div class="d-flex ">

                                    <small class="w-50 text-center py-2">
                                        <a class="text-body" href=""><i
                                                class="fa fa-shopping-bag text-primary me-2"></i>Add to cart</a>
                                    </small>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: You might consider not using the conventional row/col structure and just use [flexbox](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/utilities/flex/). It doesn't care how many child elements there are.

Comment: @easleyfixed, if you find yourself writing four lengthy comments, just post an answer. It makes a bit of a mess to leave all that there.

Comment: Type up too many answers for people to not accept them, use them or ignore them, so I make sure what they want is good in comments, then type up an answer from it.  But still not answer from OP, and now someone else has basically expanded my answer ..  but I delete my comments afterwards usually and make a real answer, IF the OP decides its useful to them, which hasn't happened yet.  But yeah flexbox is a good idea too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can modify the number of cols in an row with classes `row-cols-<number of cols>` do it as mobile ej. `row-cols-md-<number of cols under md devices>`
So you can try this code:

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container-fluid  py-5 m-0">
        <div class="container-fluid m-0">
            <div class="row g-0 gx-5 align-items-end">
                <div class="col-lg-6">
                    <div class="section-header text-start mb-5">
                        <span class="display-5 mb-3 fw-bolder">Os Nossos produtos</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-6 text-lg-end position-relative" style="bottom: 50px;">
                    <h5><a href="" class="mb-3" style="text-decoration: none;">View All <i class="fa-solid fa-arrow-right"></i></a></h5>

                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="tab-content">
                <div id="tab-1" class="tab-pane p-0 active">
                    <div class="row g-0 row-cols-5">
                        <div class="col">
                            <div class="product-item">
                                <div class="position-relative bg-light overflow-hidden">
                                    <img class="img-fluid w-100" src="img/imagensMiguel/produto_1.jpeg" alt="">

                                </div>
                                <div class="p-4">
                                    <a class="d-block h5 mb-2" href="">Fresh Tomato</a>
                                    <span class="text-primary me-1">$19.00</span>
                                    <span class="text-body text-decoration-line-through">$29.00</span>
                                </div>
                                <div class="d-flex ">
                                    <small class="w-50 text-center py-2">
                                        <a class="text-body" href=""><i
                                                class="fa fa-shopping-bag text-primary me-2"></i>Add to cart</a>
                                    </small>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col">
                            <div class="product-item">
                                <div class="position-relative bg-light overflow-hidden">
                                    <img class="img-fluid w-100" src="img/imagensMiguel/produto_2.jpeg" alt="">

                                </div>
                                <div class="p-4">
                                    <a class="d-block h5 mb-2" href="">Fresh Tomato</a>
                                    <span class="text-primary me-1">$19.00</span>
                                    <span class="text-body text-decoration-line-through">$29.00</span>
                                </div>
                                <div class="d-flex ">

                                    <small class="w-50 text-center py-2">
                                        <a class="text-body" href=""><i
                                                class="fa fa-shopping-bag text-primary me-2"></i>Add to cart</a>
                                    </small>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col">
                            <div class="product-item">
                                <div class="position-relative bg-light overflow-hidden">
                                    <img class="img-fluid w-100" src="img/imagensMiguel/produto_3.png" alt="">

                                </div>
                                <div class=" p-4">
                                    <a class="d-block h5 mb-2" href="">Fresh Tomato</a>
                                    <span class="text-primary me-1">$19.00</span>
                                    <span class="text-body text-decoration-line-through">$29.00</span>
                                </div>
                                <div class="d-flex ">

                                    <small class="w-50 text-center py-2">
                                        <a class="text-body" href=""><i
                                                class="fa fa-shopping-bag text-primary me-2"></i>Add to cart</a>
                                    </small>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col">
                            <div class="product-item">
                                <div class="position-relative bg-light overflow-hidden">
                                    <img class="img-fluid w-100" src="img/imagensMiguel/produto_1.jpeg" alt="">

                                </div>
                                <div class=" p-4">
                                    <a class="d-block h5 mb-2" href="">Fresh Tomato</a>
                                    <span class="text-primary me-1">$19.00</span>
                                    <span class="text-body text-decoration-line-through">$29.00</span>
                                </div>
                                <div class="d-flex ">

                                    <small class="w-50 text-center py-2">
                                        <a class="text-body" href=""><i
                                                class="fa fa-shopping-bag text-primary me-2"></i>Add to cart</a>
                                    </small>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col">
                            <div class="product-item">
                                <div class="position-relative bg-light overflow-hidden">
                                    <img class="img-fluid w-100" src="img/imagensMiguel/produto_2.jpeg" alt="">

                                </div>
                                <div class=" p-4">
                                    <a class="d-block h5 mb-2" href="">Fresh Tomato</a>
                                    <span class="text-primary me-1">$19.00</span>
                                    <span class="text-body text-decoration-line-through">$29.00</span>
                                </div>
                                <div class="d-flex ">

                                    <small class="w-50 text-center py-2">
                                        <a class="text-body" href=""><i
                                                class="fa fa-shopping-bag text-primary me-2"></i>Add to cart</a>
                                    </small>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col">
                            <div class="product-item">
                                <div class="position-relative bg-light overflow-hidden">
                                    <img class="img-fluid w-100" src="img/imagensMiguel/produto_3.png" alt="">

                                </div>
                                <div class=" p-4">
                                    <a class="d-block h5 mb-2" href="">Fresh Tomato</a>
                                    <span class="text-primary me-1">$19.00</span>
                                    <span class="text-body text-decoration-line-through">$29.00</span>
                                </div>
                                <div class="d-flex ">

                                    <small class="w-50 text-center py-2">
                                        <a class="text-body" href=""><i
                                                class="fa fa-shopping-bag text-primary me-2"></i>Add to cart</a>
                                    </small>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

More info here: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/layout/grid/#row-columns